# Intel Pentium Assembler x86 assembler code generation

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86

Thanks in advance for your time! I am currently working on making a mini pascal compiler. Scan, parse and semantic analysis are working and I am in the code-generation phase. I have come across some code I have generated that I do not fully understand why it does not work. It can compile, but the output is completely off. I will first link the sample program and then the assembler code generated.

```
type recordType = record of {
                x: int,
                y: int
              };

func a(x : int, y : int) : recordType
  var p2 : recordType;
  allocate p2;
  p2.x = x;
  p2.y = y;
  return p2;
end a

var p1 : recordType;
p1 = a(10,2);

write p1.x / p1.y;
```

As the assembler code is quite large (due to no optimization has been done yet), I will link the code for the function a, as I think the problem lies there. If you would like the full example I will be happy to post it, but I will not spam the forum unless asked to.

The assembler code for the function a looks like this:

```
a:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    lea -8(%ebp), %eax
    pushl %eax
    popl %eax
    imul $8, %eax
    pushl %eax
    call malloc
    addl $4, %esp
    movl %eax, -8(%ebp)
    lea -8(%ebp), %eax
    pushl %eax
    popl %eax
    addl $4, %eax
    pushl %eax
    movl 12(%ebp), %eax
    pushl %eax
    popl %eax
    popl %ebx
    movl %eax, (%ebx)
    lea -8(%ebp), %eax
    pushl %eax
    popl %eax
    addl $0, %eax
    pushl %eax
    movl 8(%ebp), %eax
    pushl %eax
    popl %eax
    popl %ebx
    movl %eax, (%ebx)
    movl -8(%ebp), %eax
    pushl %eax
    popl %eax
    jmp aend
aend:
   movl %ebp, %esp
   popl %ebp
   ret
```

Now before you say anything. I know there are alot of redundant code and that is because I am yet to optimize the code. That being said, I would like to say something about the conventions used. The parameters x and y are saved +offset from the basepointer (%ebp) according to their size (int, bool and array is 4 bytes, where as records have a total size equal to the sum of the size of their members) and the local variables are saved with a -offset according to the basepointer (params start at +8 and locals start at -4). Remember that assembler in AT&T style uses the convention movl src, dst, which is different from normal assembler.

I think the problem might lie in the mix between the lea instruction and the movl or my indexing according to the basepointer. Anyways it can compile and gives me a consisten result of 3, when it should be 5. I have tested my division and it seems to work with "normal" integers.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Regards
Magnus

Answer (score 0):

Because `lea -8(%ebp),%eax` calculates an address the instruction `imul $8,%eax` multiplies an address by 8... Why?

The code `movl %eax,-8(%ebp)` stores %eax below the stackpointer. So this value will not survive for very long!

The code `movl %eax,(%ebx)` also stores below the stackpointer because %ebx by now contains effective address -4(%ebp). 10 lines down this happens a second time when %ebx contains effective address -8(%ebp).

Perhaps what you need to do is replace the third instruction with `subl $8,%esp` and `movl %esp,%eax`. This would really establish an area for your local variables.